Why is 男 pronounced "dan"?
In 漢音 , the word for man 男 is pronounced dan, instead of nan. Where does the initial D come from when none of the chinese dialects say this character with an initial D? The only one whichi can think of is the hokkien language where the initial N changed to L and proceedingly this L can be pronounced like a D, but I don't believe that japanese sourced the word from modern hokkienese so where does this reading come from?

Because "prenasalized stops". Google that yourself, with the name "Marc Miyake", who has documented about those pretty well in his publications. Here's a Reddit answer to get you started.
